# Using Sharepoint column format to show button for files only using JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have added the following JSON code to sharepoint to show a button to request document approval, however I want to limit this to only show the button against files not folders using the Boolean `IsFolder`.

[image]

[image]

However I am really new to all of this and cannot work out what expressions I need to add to implement this filter.

Any and all help would be great!

Comment: Is `IsFolder` custom column created by you or SharePoint default property?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the button for folders based on `Content Type` like:

```
"style": {
    "visibility": "=if([$ContentType] == 'Folder', 'hidden', 'visible')"
}
```

OR

```
"style": {
    "display": "=if([$ContentType] == 'Folder', 'none', 'block')"
}
```

You can refer to this JSON sample which uses same expression to hide the button for folders: [Download File Button](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/generic-download-file-button)